# scala operators as methods in java

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

When manipulating scala objects (primarily from the the scala.collection package) the operator overloaded functions seem to be available to be used in Java.

i.e. in scala

```
var s = Set(1, 2, 3)
var t = s + 4
var x = s | t
```

so in Java, looking at `scala.collection.Set` in eclipse autocomplete, I can see the prototypes

[image: eclipse screenshot]

But I'm unable to use them correctly

```
import scala.collection.Set;

Set<Integer> s = new Set<Integer>();
Set<Integer> t = s.$plus(4); /* compile error with javac, or runtime error with eclipse/*
```

How are these scala methods meant to be used from within Java?

Comment: I guess it's not problem of method names per se: the cause is likely scala collection hierarchy and contravariance: javac fails to deem `scala.collection.Set<String>` as `scala.collection.immutable.Set<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you can't code to some scala interfaces in Java!
This code compiles and executes correctly in Sun and Eclipse.

Note the use of `HashSet` on the left hand side of the assignment

```
import scala.collection.HashSet;

public class TestCase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();

        HashSet<String> set4 = set2.$plus("test");

        System.out.println(set2.size());
        System.out.println(set4.size());


    }
}
```

**Why is this the case?**

I believe it has something to do with Scalas ability to inherit multiple traits, which java eclipse doesn't understand.

For instance, HashSet extends `AbstractSet, Set, GenericSetTemplate,SetLike, FlatHashTable, CustomParallelizable, Serializable` some of which are interfaces some of which are AbstractClasses.

The `.$plus()` Method would appear to come from `SetLike`, not `Set`, which would explain why calling the method on the `Set` Supertype would cause this error.

That said I still can't refer to `HashSet` using the Supertype `SetLike` as that still fails, and thats as far as I can go.

I think the main problem here is Elipse somehow misrepresenting the Supertype as having as those methods, which is wrong.